# How to refresh multiple elements with similar class using jsviews

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

```
$.view(class).refresh()
```

Above code only works on the first element, if there are multiple elements with the same class. Is there any way by which i can update multiple elements with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.view(".myClass")` returns a single view (for the first `".myClass"` element found).

But you can do:

`$(".myClass").each(function() {
  $.view(this).refresh();
})`

which will refresh each of the `".myClass"` views.